# ORA-00979 - SQL - Not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: sql

Im getting into SQL, does anybody could give me a hand, to handel the following exception

```
SELECT e.job_id,
COUNT (e.employee_id) AS num_employees,
SUM(e.salary) AS Sum_salary,
e.salary - j.min_salary AS diff_min,
(e.salary - j.max_salary)*-1 AS diff_max
FROM employees e
JOIN jobs j
ON (e.job_id = j.job=id)
GROUP BY e.job_id;
```

Comment: missing "," comma after your e.job_id

Comment: I did fixed, however the error I got still ORA-00979

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
SELECT e.job_id,
COUNT (e.employee_id) AS num_employees,
SUM(e.salary) AS Sum_salary,
sum(e.salary - j.min_salary) AS diff_min,
sum((e.salary - j.max_salary)*-1) AS diff_max
FROM employees e
JOIN jobs j
ON (e.job_id = j.job=id)
GROUP BY e.job_id;
```

Comment: you are aggregating the salary by `job_id`, `e.salary-j.min_salary` is not aggregation